# Input field prevents page from scrolling on iphone

Tags: ios, css, input, scroll

Im working on a site that has a lot of forms. I have noticed that when you scroll/swipe the site on an iphone the page does not scroll if your finger is on an input field. To scroll you have to aim your finger on the body kind of.

Anyone having some ideas on what causes this strange behaviour?

Its just simple inputs wrapped in a form tag.

Comment: Basically its not possible to scroll the site if the fingers swipe starting point is over an input.

Comment: did u ever found a solution for this?

Comment: I did! It was in aproject that i've had took over from another develoepr. Tha peoblem was that the former developer on purpose had implemented functionality to not be able to scroll on those inputs...

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for this issue might be :

```
function setTextareaPointerEvents(value) {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.pointerEvents = value;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTextareaPointerEvents('none');
});

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    setTextareaPointerEvents('auto');
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTextareaPointerEvents('none');
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        setTextareaPointerEvents('none');
    }, 0);
});
```

This will make Mobile Safari (others not tested so far) ignore the textareas for scrolling but allows to set focus etc. as usual.

Comment: Pretty slick solution. Thanks! Curious if anyone has been able to test this on Android?